Memory locations in Fortran: sometimes yes, sometimes no
I would like to know the reason for the difference in output between just_checking_1 and just_checking_2 in the below toy code.  I guess this boils down to what is the difference between a(*) and a(:).  Also, is there any way that subroutine just_checking_p could access the memory location to which b is pointing?
$ cat whereis.F90
program whereisit

integer, target :: a(100)
integer, pointer :: b(:)

print '("a is at 0x",Z8)', loc(a)
call just_checking_1(a)
call just_checking_2(a)

b => a
print '("b is at 0x",Z8)', loc(b)
call just_checking_p(b)

end program



subroutine just_checking_1(a)
integer :: a(*)     !<-- Noice: a(*)
print '("In just_checking_1 a is at 0x",Z8)', loc(a)
end subroutine


subroutine just_checking_2(a)
integer :: a(:)    !<-- Notice: a(:)
print '("In just_checking_2 a is at 0x",Z8)', loc(a)
end subroutine


subroutine just_checking_p(b)
integer, pointer, intent(in) :: b(:)
print '("In just checking b is at 0x",Z8)', loc(b)
end subroutine


$ ./a.out
a is at 0x  6B4140
In just_checking_1 a is at 0x  6B4140
In just_checking_2 a is at 0x       0
b is at 0x  6B4140
In just checking b is at 0x       0


The most important difference here is that a(:) as a dummy argument requires that an explicit interface to the procedure be visible to the caller; it isn't in your example. I write more about this at https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2012/01/05/doctor-fortran-gets-explicit-again/
Some compilers can diagnose this error - a non-default option may be required.

Or get used to using Implicit None( Type, External ) . The safety belts exist, you may as well use them.
